# Finding a Mathematical definition of a Discrete Time Game

Tags: combinatorics, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

**Preface:**

Suppose we have a game world as depicted in the following figure:

[image]

Where each of the white blocks is passable, And each of the black blocks is a wall and so impassable.

Each of the Green and Blue figures is a tank. Its turret determine where it is facing and to which direction it can shoot.

Now imagine that the Green tanks are controlled by some artificial intelligent player, And that the Blue tank is controlled by you.

Each tank can shoot, move and do nothing on the command of its owner (or player).

The mission of each player is to destroy the units of the other player.

---

**Problem:**

The problem is to find a **mathematically presice** definition of the game:

First we'll define the following sets and functions:

$Unit=\{Tank\}$
(The set of possible units, for simplicity we have just $Tank$)

$Player = \{1, 2\}$
(The set of players, for simplicity we have just two)

$Direction=\{Left, Right, Up, Down\}$
(A set of directions that determines which direction a tank faces, And to which direction a shell is going to)

$Shell = \{(BasicShell, -0.1)\}$
(A set of tuples of the form $(shell, damage)$ where $shell$ is the shell name, And $damage$ is the damage to inflict on when hitting a tank. For simplicity we have just one type of shell)

$PlayerShell = Player \times Shell \times Direction$
(A set of triples of the form $(player,  shell, direction)$ where $player$ is the player who shot the shell, $shell$ is a tuple that includes the shell name and its damage, And $direction$ is the direction of the shell)

$Health = (0,1]$
($1$ for full health, near $0$ for 'nearly dead', Note: $0$ is not a possible value for health since if a $Unit$ has $0$ health then it is dead and gets immediatly removed from the game world (or $State$))

$PlayerUnit = Player\times Unit\times Health\times Direction$
(A set of quadruples of the form $(player,  unit, health, direction)$ where $player$ is the player who owns the unit, $unit$ is the unit type, $health$ is the health of the unit, $direction$ is the direction the unit is facing)

$BlockState = \{Free, Wall\}\cup PlayerUnit \cup PlayerShell $
(The set of possible states that a block on a grid can be, $Free$ means passable block and $Wall$ means impassable block, The other values for a block indicate wether a tank or a shell is on the block)

$State = \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{M}_{m\times n}^{BlockState}$
(A tuple of the form $(time, grid\_configuration)$ where $time$ is the time passed since the start of the game, And $grid\_configuration$ is the current game world state which is an $m\times n$ matrix over $BlockState$, Assume that $\mathbb{N}$ is the set of natural numbers (includes $0$)).

$Action = \{None, Left, Right, Up, Down, Shoot\}$
(The set of actions that a tank can take)

$Win:State\longrightarrow Player\cup\{Draw, Ongoing\}$
(A function that given a state determines the winner of the game, If the game is still ongoing and if its draw (I.e. no tanks on the grid))

$S_{init}\in State$
(The beginning configuration of the game world)

---

Now the problem is to **mathematically** define the function:
$Transition:State\times 2^{ApplicableActions}\longrightarrow State $

That will return the next state after applying a subset of the set of applicable actions in the current state.

Where $ApplicableActions = \{\text{The set of applicable actions for each player in the current state}\}$.

(Surely $Transition$ cannot let tanks move through walls and destroy walls by shooting on them)

I think there is some problem in the definition of the $Transition$ function, Since $ApplicableActions$ depends on the current state, And since $Transition$ takes a $State$ and an $ApplicableAction$.

(Note: Since the game is Real-Time each one of the players can move simultanousely, In contast to Turn-Based games)

**Clarifications**
Assume that the tanks and shots move in discrete steps,
And that shots move twice as faster as a tank, (It has some consequence on the $Transition$ function), Also a shot hits the first tank it encounters and then the shot got removed from the world (or state), Also assume that shots harm only tanks of other players.

Thanks.

(Note: You can check the following link for more information: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.1940.pdf)

(After that I want to execute on the State-Space of this game a Time-Based Minimax algorithm).

Comment: I don't think there is any problem since you can define $Transition$  in such a way that the action are actually applicable in the given state. An other way to do it would be to define the strategies of the players that given a state (or a sequence of states if you wish) return an applicable action, the resulting state is then the composition of the strategies. Does that help you?

Comment: @wece Yes, but because $Transition$ takes a $State$ and a subset of $Action$s that are applicable in the $State$ passed to $Transition$, There is a little problem in the definition of the domain of the function $Transition$.

Comment: You can define transition as $Transition:State\times Actions \rightarrow State\cup\{\bot\}$ such that $Transition(s,a)\in State$ if a is applicable in $s$ and $Transition(s,a)=\bot$ otherwise.

Comment: @wece But how can I define the set of applicable actions for each tank? Maybe as a set of vectors $a\in Action^N$ where $N$ is the number of tanks **currently** in the game world? Also what contents the $Actions$ set that you wrote should contain? Every possible action for each tank in the game world (And maybe even imaginable tanks (I.e tanks not on the game board)) ? Also I am looking for a definition that is relatively efficient to run on a computer, Thanks.

Comment: @wece Also I'd like to ask you how to resolve the case where two tanks want to come to the same block. Thanks.

Comment: I feel you've left out some details as to how the game works. Do the players move in discrete steps? If not, do they move at constant speed, or can they accelerate and decelerate? If motion is continuous, then when is a tank considered to leave one square and enter the next? If a square is shot at and a tank is partially on that square, is that a hit?

Comment: @JackM I Assume that the players and shots move in discrete steps, (Continuous transition between the discrete states will be simulated by some animation (But this is related to the Rendering system and not the AI system)), Also I want shots to move twice as faster than a tank.

Comment: @MathNerd So if it's in discrete steps, why are you modelling time by a real number? Just use an integer.

Comment: @JackM Thanks a lot, I've changed the values that time can take to $\mathbb{N}$ (The set of natural numbers). (By the way, every Real-Time game have cycles in which it updates the AI, So $\mathbb{N}$ seems great for defining time in terms of AI-cycle time)